# Как через DOM дерево при нажатии на кнопку высвечивался alert с моим текстом и текстом html элемента?

Tags: html, dom

```
let arrFish = document.getElementsByClassName('fish-list-card-name')

function eventAlertClick (e) {
  console.log()
  alert (`Подтвердите, что хотите купить рыбу`) 
}

let eventClick = document.querySelectorAll('button')

for (let i = 0;i < eventClick.length; i++) {
  eventClick[i].addEventListener('click', eventAlertClick)
}
```

// 1 строчка это массив имен рыб, не понимаю как мне развесить на кнопке alert и обращаться к конкретной рыбе на странице, не меняя разметку html

Comment: "не понимаю как" - Мы тоже не понимаем, так как из вопроса совершенно не видно, какая связь между кнопками и рыбами. "Вы рыбов продаете?"

Comment: на кнопке обработчики событий, при нажатии вверху появляется алерт с моим текстом, но мне надо чтобы был мой текст и имя рыбы

Comment: я не знаю как обратится к нужному элементу при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: Мы тоже не знаем. Что такое "нужный элемент"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
addEventListener(`click`, e => {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains(`buy-fish`)) return;

  alert(`Подтвердите, что хотите купить ${e.target.dataset.name}?`);
});
```

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Окунь
  <button data-name='окунёв' class='buy-fish'>Купить</button>
</div>
<div>
  Карась
  <button data-name='карасёв' class='buy-fish'>Купить</button>
</div>
<div>
  Щука
  <button data-name='щуков' class='buy-fish'>Купить</button>
</div>
```